Snowflake kafka connector encrypted aes256 key fips 140-2 compliant?
Following the below url to set up Snowflake kafka connector
snowflake kafka connector
I then use the private key and pass phrase in the connector config and deploy to connect instance
I see the following error

Blockquote
2024-09-16 01:51:21,988 ERROR [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Validate: Error connecting to snowflake:[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Exception: Invalid encrypted private key or passphrase
Error Code: 0018
Detail: failed to decrypt private key. Please verify input private key and passphrase. Snowflake Kafka Connector only supports encryption algorithms in FIPS 140-2
Message: unable to read encrypted data: Failed to construct sequence from byte[]: Extra data detected in stream
org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:83)

i am using this command to generate the key

Blockquote
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 aes256 -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8

Isn't aes256 not FIPS 140-2 compliant? Online lookup seems like it is.
